# How to add confirm box before submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am a new developer and I have a problem. I think you can solve this. I want to show confirm box before delete. How Can I do that this my Ajax code
**HTML:**

```
<input type='button' class="btn btn-danger delete_button" id="delete_button<?php echo $row->id;?>" value="delete" onclick="delete_row('<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
```

**ajax**

```
function delete_row(id)
{
 jQuery.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: "/blue_bucket/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=delete_form",  
    data:{
            delete_row:'delete_row',
            row_id:id,
        },
    success:function(response) {
        if(response=="success")
        {
            var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        }
        top.location.href="admin.php?page=data_list";
    }
 });
}
```

**Wordpress PHP**

```
function delete_form()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['delete_row']))         
        {
            $id=$_POST['row_id'];
            echo $row_no;
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = "countries";
            $wpdb->delete($table_name, 
                        array( 'id' => $id ) );
            exit();
        }    
    }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_form', 'delete_form' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_form', 'delete_form');
```

Comment: Before sending the ajax request, get a confirmation from user using confirm box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`confirm`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmpuDz8vbTAhWEN48KHTlCB7QQFggsMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_win_confirm.asp&usg=AFQjCNEAtwkyKxluDLGhQO03IiyYHPpwaw&sig2=eePtes_90YnDBcaAjrlNrg) Method

```
function delete_row(id)
{
if(!confirm('Are you sure to delet')){
return false;
}
 jQuery.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: "/blue_bucket/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=delete_form",  
    data:{
            delete_row:'delete_row',
            row_id:id,
        },
    success:function(response) {
        if(response=="success")
            {
            var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
            }
            top.location.href="admin.php?page=data_list";
    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put confirmbox before ajax call, see below code

```
function delete_row(id)
{
if (confirm("Do you want to delete?") == true) {
 jQuery.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: "/blue_bucket/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=delete_form",  
    data:{
            delete_row:'delete_row',
            row_id:id,
        },
    success:function(response) {
        if(response=="success")
            {
            var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
            }
            top.location.href="admin.php?page=data_list";
    }
 });
}
}
```

Comment: Technically right but I would use `!confirm` and return early so the whole process isn't in the `if` statement.

Comment: anyways for if condition false, it will skip all code and return

Comment: I understand that but it just makes the code look cleaner and not have another layer of indenting it doesn't need :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this as a first line to your delete_row():

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) { // code inside this... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code I have:
https://github.com/delboy1978uk/bs-delete-confirm

If you use Bootstrap in your project (EDIT - I just noticed you are! :-D), just follow the README.md! All it takes is to add a class to the button you want the confirm modal hooked up to. If not, take a look at the actual code, and tweak the HTML to whatever, and edit the javascript call or the popup dialog:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        deleteConfirm: function(options)
        {
            var defaults =
            {
                heading: "Please confirm",
                body: 'Are you sure you wish to perform this action?',
                ok_text: 'Proceed',
                cancel_text: 'Back',
                log: false
            };

            options = $.extend(defaults,options);

            $('body').append('<div class="modal fade" id="bs-delete-confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bs-delete-confirm-label" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title" id="bs-delete-confirm-label">Please confirm</h4></div><div id="bs-delete-confirm-body" class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><a id="bs-delete-confirm-cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></a><a id="bs-delete-confirm-ok" class="btn btn-primary"></a></div></div></div></div>');

            $('#bs-delete-confirm-label').html(options.heading);
            $('#bs-delete-confirm-body').html(options.body);
            $('#bs-delete-confirm-cancel').html(options.cancel_text);
            $('#bs-delete-confirm-ok').html(options.ok_text);

            this.each(function() {
                $(this).on('click',function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  link = $(this).prop('href');
                  $('#bs-delete-confirm-ok').prop('href',link);
                  $('#bs-delete-confirm').modal();
                  if(options.log == true){
                      console.log('Clicked link = ' + link);
                  }
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```